# Screen size for Root (super user)

Tags: screen, administrator

I am currently using LTS 16.04 and recently having issues with screen size for root / superuser / admin. Neither the applications on the left edges nor top periphery are visible. Things looks zoomed out. Neither do the key board short cuts work.

Comment: Are you logging to a desktop as root?

Comment: Yes. desktop as root and I have laptop as well. 2 different systems same problem.

Comment: It is not advised to log into Ubuntu as root.  If you can log in as a regular user, and don't have these problems, it's because of this.

Comment: Although many distributions support `root` login, Ubuntu appears to be problematic in this area.